# Send POST request to views.py from base.html template

Tags: python, django

I'm using django-notifications-hq to display notifications in the top navbar of the website, which happens to be located in the base template file, base.html. I have a small button in the navbar to set notifications to read but I'm having trouble sending the POST request to the views.py. Is there a way to send this POST request from anywhere on the website to a specific function in views.py? I've read about context processors but that only seems to help in opposite scenarios when you want to send data from views to the base template file.

Function in views.py I want to send a POST request to from base.html:

```
def mark_all_as_read(request):
    request.user.notifications.mark_all_as_read()


    return redirect('home') #ideally, just refresh the page the user is on but I can't figure that out either
```

base.html form I want to send a request from:

```
<ul class="dropdown-grid-menu" id="notice-link">
                    <a href="{% url 'messages' %}">
                      {% live_notify_list %}
                    </a>
                    <li>
                      <form method='POST'>
                      {% csrf_token %}
                      <br /><button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" href="{% url 'mark_all_as_read' %}" type="submit" role="button">Mark Read</button>
                      </form>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
```

Hoping there is an easy solution. Thanks!

EDIT: URLS.py

`path('mark_all_as_read', views.mark_all_as_read, name='mark_all_as_read'),`

Comment: You just need to add a `urls.py` entry for `mark_all_as_read`. Then you can use it in (and call it from) all your templates

Comment: so I had this in my urls.py but I how do I specify the exact function? `path('mark_all_as_read', views.mark_all_as_read, name='mark_all_as_read'),`

Comment: `views.mark_all_as_read` is the function that serves that view. I'm not sure what you mean when you want to specify the *exact function*

Comment: it's because when I submit the form it doesn't appear to be reaching the mark_all_as_read function in views.py. Not sure why it's not sending the POST request at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To specify the endpoint/url/path that you want to submit a POST request to you need to set the `action` attribute of the `form` tag

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'mark_all_as_read' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <br />
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" role="button">Mark Read</button>
</form>
```

Comment: that was it! Thank you so much. So the action attribute is needed for POST forms, and then you can use the basic href attribute for GET requests?

Comment: @winston `form`s always require the `action` attribute, for GET or POST. If you don't provide `action` the form will submit to the current URL